# Pass new object into function

Tags: c++

I have a function: `Vector::Vector integrate(Vector::Vector start, Vector::Vector end, long int elapsedtime);`, where a `Vector` is a class I've created:

```
class Vector {
    public: 
    double x, y, z;
                   Vector(); 
                   Vector::Vector addToSelf(Vector &right); 
};
```

I want to call `integrate` with a blank `Vector` for it's first parameter. The constructor for the `Vector` does this by default, so I'm trying to do this:

`acceleration = integrate(Vector::Vector blank, wc.readAccelerometer(), time);`.

However, this gives me errors:

`error: expected primary-expression before ‘blank’`.

I thought perhaps I didn't need to give the `Vector` a name when I create it in the `integrate` function call:

`acceleration = integrate(Vector::Vector, wc.readAccelerometer(), time);`

but this gives me the same error:

`expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token`.

I could always pass in a pointer, change the `integrate` signature to match, but this seems unnecessarily messy. I could also create a new `Vector`, *then* pass it to `integrate`:

```
Vector::Vector blank;
acceleration = integrate(blank, wc.readAccelerometer(), time);
```

which works without errors, but I would have thought doing it on one go would be possible. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Thanks to Karl von Moor's comment, I've fixed it - change `Vector::Vector` to `Vector` (because I'm not defining namespaces) and everything works. Thanks.

Comment: Is `Vector` also a namespace or what do I have to understand by `Vector::Vector`?

Comment: The class `Vector` is in default namespace. What do you meant by `Vector::Vector blank;` ?

Comment: @Karl von Moor I haven't defined any namespaces. Swapping `Vector::Vector` to `Vector` fixes things - I'd just refactored `Vector` from a class `struct` to it's own class, and didn't click to the fact that I shouldn't be referencing it as I was. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is not correct C++ syntax:

```
acceleration = integrate(Vector::Vector blank, wc.readAccelerometer(), time);
```

To create a default-constructed `Vector` object, use `Vector()`:

```
acceleration = integrate(Vector(), wc.readAccelerometer(), time);
```

In C++11, you can also write `Vector{}` or even `{}` to construct a value-initialized object.

Note that usually you want to pass "large" objects by reference to const to avoid unnecessary copies.  So try changing your declaration of `integrate` to:

```
Vector integrate(const Vector& start, const Vector& end, long int elapsedtime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use scope resolution operator in a class declaration and function's parameter names. So remove `Vector::` until you are not defining the function. Example :

```
// declaration
class A {
A(); 
void f(int x);
};

// definitions
A::A(){/*...*/};

A::f(int x){/*...*/}; //note that the parameter x doesn't have a `::`
```